# When Cursor is Locked can't interact with 3D EventTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For Context, I use Unity's basic FirstPersonController. I've made a cube with a **Collider** and an **EventTrigger** OnPointerEnter. I do have an **EventSystem** in my hierarchy and my camera have a **PhysicRaycaster**.

But when I look with the center of my screen towards the cube, no event is triggered. However if I set the cursor lockState to None it works perfectly fine !
Why doesn't it work when the `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked` ? (The cursor is supposed to still be here but invisibe and at the center of the screen right ?)

Comment: I think by being invisible it stops doing things like triggering events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just because OnPointerEnter is called if you move your cursor and then if it enters the object, in this case cursor is locked at center so cursor isn't moving.

You can try using raycast to check for object.

But **if you want to use methods such as pointer enter and exit then** add this script to your camera and use `ICameraCatchable` interface to use `CastPointerEnter()` and `CastPointerExit()` methods.

**Script attach to camera:**

```
using UnityEngine;
public class CameraRaycaster : MonoBehaviour
{
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray;
ICameraCatchable LastCastCatcher;
ICameraCatchable currentCastCatcher;
void Update()
{
    ray = new(transform.position, transform.forward);
    currentCastCatcher = null;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)
        && hit.transform.TryGetComponent(out currentCastCatcher)
        && LastCastCatcher != currentCastCatcher)
    {
        LastCastCatcher?.CastPointerExit();
        LastCastCatcher = currentCastCatcher;
        currentCastCatcher.CastPointerEnter();
    }
    else if (currentCastCatcher == null)
    {
        LastCastCatcher?.CastPointerExit();
        LastCastCatcher = null;
    }
}
}

public interface ICameraCatchable
{
public void CastPointerEnter();
public void CastPointerExit();
}
```

**Test class:**

```
using UnityEngine;
public class TestObj : MonoBehaviour, ICameraCatchable
{
    public void CastPointerEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("Camera is focus on me.", this);
    }

    public void CastPointerExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Camera is not focus on me anymore.", this);
    }
}
```